# Based on String return Array in Access 2010 vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I've been working on this for two days and thrashing around and here's where I am now.

```
Private Function SetColumns(sRptVer As String, iColumns() As Integer)

If sRptVer = "Q1" Then
    iColumns(1) = 5 '<- Subscript out of range error here Hovering shows _
                    '"iColumns(1)=<Subscript out of range>"
    iColumns(2) = 6
    iColumns(3) = 7
    iColumns(4) = 17
End If

If sRptVer = "Q2" Then
    iColumns(1) = 5
    iColumns(2) = 6
    iColumns(3) = 7
    iColumns(4) = 8
    iColumns(5) = 9
    iColumns(6) = 10
    iColumns(7) = 17
End If

SetColumns = iColumns()

End Function

Private Sub Test2()

Dim iColValue() As Integer
Dim sRptVer As String
Dim iColumns() As Integer

sRptVer = "Q1"

iColValue() = SetColumns(sRptVer, iColumns())

For i = 1 To 10

    Debug.Print iColValue(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

The goal is to be able to be able to pass a string designating the quarter and return an array that will serve to set the columns I will iterate over to get values out of an Excel spreadsheet. (I'm pulling data from Excel into Access). 
I've tried starting with iColumns(0). No difference.
NOTE: Access vba does not like to set arrays like so iColumns()={1,2,3,4}. It balks at the "{}".
Access vba doesn't seem to like "ReDim" either, I get a compile error: Syntax error when I "redim icolumns() as Integer" in the SetColumns function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `Dim iColValue() As Integer` to `ReDim iColValue(10) as Integer()`, then `Dim iColumns() As Integer` to `ReDim iColumns(10) as Integer` and then add `as Integer()` to the end of function definition. That should get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two separate arrays in your calling procedure to do what you want.  Try this instead:

```
Private Function SetColumns(sRptVer As String) As Integer()
    Dim iColumns() As Integer
    Select Case sRptVer
    Case "Q1"
        ReDim iColumns(1 To 4)
        iColumns(1) = 5
        iColumns(2) = 6
        iColumns(3) = 7
        iColumns(4) = 17
    Case "Q2"
        ReDim iColumns(1 To 7)
        iColumns(1) = 5
        iColumns(2) = 6
        iColumns(3) = 7
        iColumns(4) = 8
        iColumns(5) = 9
        iColumns(6) = 10
        iColumns(7) = 17
    End Select
    SetColumns = iColumns
End Function

Private Sub Test2()
    Dim sRptVer As String
    Dim iColValue() As Integer

    sRptVer = "Q1"

    iColValue() = SetColumns(sRptVer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(iColValue) To UBound(iColValue)
        Debug.Print iColValue(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

I made a few other changes:

- I used ReDim to dynamically size the array based on the parameter passed to SetColumns.
- I passed both lower and upper bounds to the array in the ReDim statement.  Arrays in VBA are zero-bound by default*, so `ReDim iColumns(4)` is actually equivalent to `ReDim iColumns(0 To 4)`.
- Because we no longer know the size of the array ahead of time, I use the `LBound()` and `UBound()` functions to walk the array.
- I changed your two If statements to a Select...Case statement.  Based on your limited sample code that you provided this seemed appropriate.  If your actual code is more complex, it may not be.

*NOTE: Unfortunately, you can change the starting array base in VBA using the [`Option Base` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx).  Please don't do this.  Ever.  You will only confuse yourself and others.  If you want a specific array to start from 1 then be explicit when you Dim or ReDim the array as I showed in my example.

Comment: Thanks again. I've been incorporating this into the larger real project and it's working great and more robust than the direction I was headed.